# Jquery: blur not triggering event after clicking out of focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to have an Ajax event trigger after clicking out of an inline edit.  Can't get the blur to trigger when clicking out of focus.

HTML:

```
<span class="tb">sdaf</span>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('document').ready(function(){   
    $( "span.tb" ).on( "click", function() {
     var $this = $(this); // this is clicked span.
     var html = $this.html();
      $this.replaceWith('<textarea name="newDesc" style="width:100%;">'+html + '\r\n </textarea>').html().focus();
      $this.blur(function() {
       alert("out of focus");
       // trigger Ajax event here to save new data
       $this.replaceWith('<span class="tb">'+html + '\r\n </span>').html();       
      })
    })
 });
</script>
```

JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4mvj8dg6/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do have any issues with using `contenteditable` ?

You can skip the whole jQuery business with

```
<span class="tb" contenteditable>sdaf</span>
```

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/4mvj8dg6/3/)

**EDIT**
If you have to use jQuery, your code could look [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/mcb3unL5/)

```
$('document').ready(function(){   
    function inputGen(el, content){
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.className = 'tmpTxt';
        textarea.name = 'newDesc'; 
        textarea.style.width = '100%';
        textarea.value = content;

        el.html(textarea);

        $('.tmpTxt').focus();

        $('.tmpTxt').on('blur', function(){
          el.removeClass('active');
          el.html( $(this).val() );
        })
    }

    $( "span.tb" ).on( "click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( !$this.hasClass('active') ) {
            inputGen( $this, $this.html() );
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks WIlson.  Appreciate it.  I have multiple <spans> that I am displaying mySQL data within each span.  To do the AJAX update how does one pass the id of each span so that when the user clicks out of the span and AJAX fires the correct ID is passed to update the table with the correct updated info? `<br /><span class="tb" value=<?php echo $elementid; ?>>sdaf</span><br /> `

Comment: How would one then get the value of the $elementid so that I can pass it as a var using AJAX?

Comment: From that example you'd do something like `$('.myElement').attr('value')`

But I think you should have a `data-value` and go for `$('.myElement').attr('data-value')` or `$('.myElement').data('value')`

Other than that, you could add an id instead of a value, I might have misread what you're trying to achieve there.

Spans don't have values the same way an input does